# Laravel base table not found using pivot model

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Hi im trying to query my tasks table. A little background information on the tables and how they are related.

Users, create Projects and Tasks, Statuses for projects and tasks can be selected from the status table, users make their own, i plan to have default ones but users may want to create their own.

By default i want to find all the users tasks where the `status_name` which is held in the `statuses` table `does not` `equal` closed. I decided it would be best to actually create a table called `task_status` which holds the `task_id` as well as the `status_id`. I still want to find the logged in users tasks and then find the status name based on the `status_id` held in the tasks table, which can be referenced in the `statuses` table. I then want to only display the any records not equal to `closed` but the first part which is explained below is trickier than first anticipated.

## My table structures can be found below:

### Table structure

#### Users

```
id | username | email
```

#### Tasks

```
id | user_id | client_id | project_id | status_id | task_name | task_brief
```

#### Statuses

```
id | status_name
```

#### Projects

```
id | user_id | client_id | status_id | type_id | project_name | project_brief
```

#### task_status

```
id | user_id | task_id | status_id
```

I'm trying to query my db simply first so that I can be sure that the data returned is correct. So I've changed my query to the below:

```
$user = User::with(array('tasks', 'task.status', 'tasks.taskstatus',
        'tasks.clients'))->find(Auth::user()->id);
```

and I'm trying to return as follows (please bear in mind I also want to query the status table so that I am able to return the name of the status):

```
@foreach($user->tasks as $task) 
{{ $task->task_name }} 
    @if(!is_null($task->clients)) 
        {{ $task->clients->client_code }}
        @endif
        @if(!is_null($task->taskstatus)) 
            {{ $task->taskstatus->status_name }}
        @endif
@endforeach
```

### My models:

#### Task.php

```
public function status(){
    return $this->hasOne('Status', 'status_id');
} 

public function taskstatus() {
    return $this->hasMany('TaskStatus', 'status_id');
}
```

#### Status.php

```
public function tasks() 
{
    return $this->hasMany('Task');
}   

public function taskstatus()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('TaskStatus', 'status_id');
    }
```

#### TaskStatus.php

```
public function tasks() 
{
    return $this->hasMany('Task', 'task_id');
}   

public function status() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Status', 'status_id')
}
```

#### However using the above returns the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 
'imanage.task_statuses' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `task_statuses` 
 where `task_statuses`.`status_id` in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)) 
(Bindings: array ( 0 => 1, 1 => 2, 2 => 3, 3 => 4, 4 => 5, 5 => 6, 6 => 7, ))
```

I'm sure that its my relationships that are defined incorrectly but I am not sure how to correct these.Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this code:

```
$user = User::whereHas('task.status', function($q)
            {
              $q->where('status', '!=', 'close');
            })
            ->with('task', 'task.clients')
            ->where('id', Auth::user()->id)
            ->first();
```

Check the eloquent docs on [querying relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#querying-relations).

also remember **DO NOT ECHO VIEW**, `return` the view instead.

Comment: i recieve this error: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'has' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `has` = ? and `id` = ? limit 1) (Bindings: array ( 0 => 'task.status', 1 => 1, ))` its still trying to query the user table for the status name. any ideas?

Comment: oops. i think whereHas should come before with. updated my answer.

Comment: same error: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'has' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `has` = ? and `id` = ? limit 1) (Bindings: array ( 0 => 'task.status', 1 => 1, ))`

Comment: try changing `whereHas` to `has`. Like `User::has(...`

Comment: updated my answer. change to. `->where('id', Auth::user()->id)`. dont use `find()` for relationship queries.

Comment: same error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'has' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `has` = ? and `id` = ? limit 1) (Bindings: array ( 0 => 'task.status', 1 => 1, ))

Comment: any ideas on the query?

Answer (score 0):

The error seems related to the fact that Laravel (well, actually Eloquent) is **getting the wrong table name**: below you have `task_statuses` instead of `task_status`. Remember that Eloquent will attempt to *pluralize* named models to get the table name.

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 
'imanage.task_statuses' doesn't exist
```

So either rename your table to match Laravel expectations, or in your model specify a [custom table name](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#basic-usage):

```
class TaskStatus extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'task_status';

    ...
```

---

Additionally, this part of your code is unclear to me:

```
Task.php

public function status(){
    return $this->hasOne('Status', 'status_id');
} 

public function taskstatus() {
    return $this->hasMany('TaskStatus', 'status_id');
}
```

Does your Task have **one** status, or does it have **many** statuses?

Comment: if i do either of the two I get the following error: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::task()`

Comment: Don't your models extend `\Eloquent`? You do have a `tasks()` method in User? -- wait. `task()`, you say? Where do you call `task()` in the singular form?

Comment: yes it extends eloquent, the task can only have one status and i call task in singular when i get the task name `@foreach($user->tasks as $task) {{ $task->task_name }}`

Comment: `$user->tasks()` uses a *plural* call. Then `$task` is an object (or maybe null). But you can't get an error about `task()`, as you do, if you call `tasks()` which is a different function altogether. Can you post the *actual code*?